# Using grouping to construct array from the value of collection| multi level group in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregate, grouping

I trying to have a group on the same collection in different fields.

Below is my collection data

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5as14e8z20e7d11a78b6b5e1"),
    "level" : "beginner",
    "type" : "middleLayer",
    "description" : "Iron crust execution",
    "usage" : '1.6mmC'
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ws16a8z20e6d11a78b6b4e3"),
    "level" : "beginner",
    "type" : "middleLayer",
    "description" : "Steel crust execution",
    "usage" : '1.5mmC'
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ws16a8z20e7d11a78b6b4e2"),
    "level" : "intermediate",
    "type" : "topLayer",
    "description" : "Steel crust execution",
    "usage" : '1.5mmC'
}

db.getCollection("structure_design").aggregate([
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: '$level'

                        data: {
                            $addToSet: {
                                _id: '$_id',
                                type: '$type',
                                description: '$description',
                                usage: '$usage',
                                level:'$level'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        data: {
                            $map: {
                                input: '$data',
                                as: 'data',
                                in: {
                                    _id: '$$data._id',
                                    description: '$$data.description',
                                    type: '$$data.type',
                                    usage: '$$data.usage',
                                    level: '$$data.level',
                                  }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        data: {
                            $push: {
                                k: {
                                    $toString: '$_id'
                                },
                                v: '$data'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $replaceRoot: {
                        newRoot: {
                            $arrayToObject: '$data'
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]);
```

The above query gives me the below output

```
{
    "beginner" : [ 
        {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5as14e8z20e7d11a78b6b5e1"),
            "type" : "middleLayer",
            "description" : "Iron crust execution",
            "usage" : '1.6mmC'
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ws16a8z20e6d11a78b6b4e3"),
            "type" : "middleLayer",
            "description" : "Steel crust execution",
            "usage" : '1.5mmC'
        },
```

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ws16a8z20e7d11a78b6b4e2"),
"type" : "topLayer",
"description" : "Steel crust execution",
"usage" : '1.5mmC'
}
]
}

My expected Out is

```
{
    "beginner",
        layerType: [ 
        {
            "middleLayer":[
                {
                   "_id" : ObjectId("5as14e8z20e7d11a78b6b5e1"),
                   "description" : "Iron crust execution",
                   "usage" : '1.6mmC'
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ws16a8z20e6d11a78b6b4e3"),
                    "description" : "Steel crust execution",
                    "usage" : '1.5mmC'
                }
            ],
            "topLayer":[
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ws16a8z20e6d11a65b6b4a2"),
                    "type" : "top",
                    "description" : "Alloy crust execution",
                    "usage" : '1.4mmC'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I use grouping to create an array-like "middleLayer" from the value of the collection?
In the second level of grouping, I need to have an array and keep pushing the value of the grouped records to it.

Comment: How does topLayer part of beginner instead intermediate? Your output doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @Gibbs i did not copied to entire collection data and out to avoid too long post. Above i have updated, its just to understand the collection and output.